# Convert all dictionary values from array to list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dictionary and currently all the values are in an array and I'd like to convert them into lists.

For example,

```
G_array={0.0: array([ 1.,  2.]),
         1.0: array([ 6.,  0.,  7.]),
         2.0: array([  8.,   9.,  10.])
```

should become

```
G_list={0: [1, 2], 1: [6, 0, 7], 2: [8, 9, 10]}
```

I haven't been able to find a way to do this for the entire dictionary at once. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `{int(k): list(map(int,v)) for k, v in G_array.items()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
G_array={0.0: np.array([ 1.,  2.]),
         1.0: np.array([ 6.,  0.,  7.]),
         2.0: np.array([  8.,   9.,  10.])}
G_list={k:list(v) for k,v in G_array.items()}
```

Then `G_list` is `{0.0: [1.0, 2.0], 1.0: [6.0, 0.0, 7.0], 2.0: [8.0, 9.0, 10.0]}`